# mysql increment if value in other column changes

Tags: mysql

I have a simple mysql table with colums id (autoincrement), player, score, tournamentid and datetime (with trigger to update it to time altered).

[image]

I want to add a column in the database (lets call this column DAY) that automaticly increases its value if a new tournamentid is entered in the database, but only if the days between this new tournamentid and the previous one is more then 4 days. if less then 4 days then it should keep the current day number. if no earlier tournamentid exists then it should start with 1.

this because sometimes we play till late and if we start on saturday and end on sunday morning (or we play entire weekend) this should still count as same day.

is this possible?

I also tried to make this with SQL coding. My thought was in PSEUDOCODE:

```
if days_between (day1 and day2) >3
then day1 = 1 and day2 = 2
else if days_between (day1 and day2) <3
then day1 = 1 and day2 = 1
```

I ended up with a monstercode that works but is just bad coding I think:

```
select tournamentid, CreatedTime , date(CreatedTime)

,CASE
# DAY1 and DAY2
WHEN datediff(
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1), #mar 11
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1)  #feb 11
             ) >3 #28 days so TRUE
      AND
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1)=DATE(CreatedTime)
THEN 'DAY1'
WHEN datediff(
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1), #mar 11
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1)  #feb 11
             ) >3 #28 days so TRUE
      AND
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1)=DATE(CreatedTime)
THEN 'DAY2'

WHEN datediff(
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1), #mar 11
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1)  #feb 11
             ) <3 #28 days so FALSE
      AND
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1)=DATE(CreatedTime)
THEN 'DAY1'
WHEN datediff(
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1), #mar 11
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1)  #feb 11
          ) <3 #28 DAYS so FALSE
      AND
      (select distinct(DATE(CreatedTime)) from pokermax_scores as t2 order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1)=DATE(CreatedTime)
THEN 'DAY2'
ELSE 'OTHER DAY'
END  as Avond
from pokermax_scores as t1
```

Comment: More information about where `tournamentid` comes from might be needed for anyone to provide you with a reliable answer or helpful advice. (My initial impression is that the database might need restructured if possible at this point.)

Comment: Are you using anything like PHP with this?

Comment: Yes its a php scripts that i run from my smartphone. it inserts the tournament and players and updates the scores. Tournamentid is a variable to get a unique number, as you might notice its just the full date/time. I want to have the days so i can calculate average scores  at end of every night to create a graph chart.